# BindingSource for GridControl on a property holding changing instances

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have an viewmodel object which we call `MyVM` for now. It holds a list of data objects (let's say of type `MyData`, it has a `List<MyEntry>` property `ListOfEntries`) called `AllDataObjects` and has a property `CurrentSelection` returning the currently selected data object out of its list.

The mechanism responsible for changing the selected item works and assigns a different `MyData` object from `AllDataObjects` to the `CurrentSelection` property.

Now I have a DevExpress `GridControl` that needs a `DataBinding` referring to `MyVM.CurrentSelection.ListOfEntries`. However if I set this up, the binding will always point to the first ever assigned element, as when `CurrentSelection` gets a new `MyData` object instance assigned, the binding still only knows the reference to the old object.

Is there a way how I can bind my Grid to this nested property without having to reset and reinitialize the same `MyData` instance stored in `CurrentSelecton` over and over?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by letting `MyVM` implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` and having the UserControl holding my Grid listen to its `PropertyChanged` event.

```
public class MyVMClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public List<MyData> AllDataObjects { get; set; }

    private MyData CurrentSelection_ { get; set; }
    public MyData CurrentSelection
    {
        get { return CurrentSelection_; }
        set
        {
            CurrentSelection_ = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentSelection));
        }
    }


    public MyVM(List<MyData> allDataObjects)
    {
        AllDataObjects = allDataObjects;
    }
}
```

and inside the `UserControl`'s code:

```
    public void Initialize(MyVMClass myVM)
    {
        MyVM = myVM;
        MyVM.PropertyChanged += MyVM_PropertyChanged;
        MyVM_PropertyChanged();
    }

    private void MyVM_PropertyChanged(object sender=null, PropertyChangedEventArgs e=null)
    {
        if (e == null || e.PropertyName == nameof(MyVMClass.CurrentSelection))
        {
            MyBindingSource.DataSource = MyVM.CurrentSelection.ListOfEntries;
        }
    }
```